# Xamarin ListView renders blank space / rows

Tags: android, ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In general a list takes more space that it needs. Basically the question is how to avoid space wasting (on screens is pink)

There is a xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Item.Text}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
                    <Label Text="Variables" FontSize="Medium"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" BackgroundColor="Pink">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" >
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                        <Entry Text="{Binding Value}" Placeholder="{Binding Name}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <Button Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}" Text="Execute" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Pretty simple, but list view renders (ios and android) with empty space, marked list with as pink and rows as red to show it:

**When list is empty**

[image]

**When list is small**

[image]

Comment: Just to pitch in here, it's generally considered bad practice to put a ListView inside a ScrollView since both have scroll events which don't co-exist nicely due to the ListView already having a ScrollView within itself.

Comment: @StevenThewissen is there a way/practice to render a list of inputs?

Comment: Is it a fixed list? If so you could use a `TableView` with its `Intent` property set to `Form`. If it needs to be dynamic you could look into adding Entrys dynamically through page code-behind. You can still set up bindings this way.

Comment: A ListView in Xamarin.Forms isn't designed to vary it's height based on its content. This is by design based on conversations I've had with Xamarin employees in the past. 
Also, I'd like to echo @StevenThewissen and say that ListViews in ScrollViews are highly discouraged.

Comment: I would suggest you use StackLayout, cause ListView cannot adjust the height based on content. You can add children into StackLayout based on your content.