# ListView taking more height than needed and Entry being hidden

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL project.

I am working on a page that displays a post, the comments for that post, and an Entry to write a comment.

My XAML is

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <local:PostListView x:Name="Post" ItemTemplate=...>
                    </local:PostListView>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="CommentHeader" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="CommentsList" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:PostViewCell>
                                    ...
                                </local:PostViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="CommentBox" Padding="10, 5, 10, 10">
                <Entry x:Name="CommentEntry" Placeholder="Comment" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" Focused="CommentEntry_Focused" Unfocused="CommentEntry_Unfocused" TextChanged="CommentEntry_TextChanged"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The first custom ListView displays only a single post at a time but I use to so I can use the ItemTemplate feature.

My problems are:

- The whole page should scroll together (leaving the comment entry) but the first ListView covers the whole screen and only shows the comment ListView once you scroll down, it only needs about 1/5 of the page the rest is blank white space.
- The comment entry is supposed to sit on the bottom of the page but appear ontop the keyboard when focused but instead gets covered by the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For The First point you can try Grid Instead Of Stack Layout to be able control the portion of each Container.

About the second Point I suggest you take a look at 
https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap

Comment: Grid would make it so each ListView gets a portion of the screen, I want the first ListView to display taking up however much space is needed then right under it the next one, but for some reason it takes up the whole screen and the other one is under it. Is there another way besides using two listviews? The 2nd is for comments so its needed but the top displays a post which depends on ViewCell binding with ItemTemplates is there a way to display a single ViewCell?

Comment: @Dan about the list view which is taking the whole screen I am facing the same issue and I think that's happen because you are using list view inside a scroll view, some sort of conflict happens in that case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996310/xamarin-listview-renders-blank-space-rows

Comment: you can force the List view height, say if you want the List height to be half the page just add yourlistview.HeightRequest=0.5*this.Height; I am gonna apply this solution for now.

Comment: about the comments there is a suggestion to try to use the footer .
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38603083/7127002

Comment: The footer idea seems to work perfectly! Is there any other way to make the Entry appear on top the keyboard though? I don't know if this matters but it has its own StackLayout with a send button I  need the whole layout to appear ontop the keyboard, isnt this possible with a scrollview? @AhmedSayed

Comment: Take a look at this package but it seems it supports only ios.
https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap

Comment: You could take a look at this solution as well, It seems that it is applicable with all platforms
https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/